# How to customize a bibliographic style?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using UTM Malaysia bibliographic style. The style is available [here](https://github.com/utmthesis/utmthesis/blob/master/utmthesis-authordate.bst). 
This style is producing the references as below.

[image]

The citation inside the text also uses the word 'and' like

[image]

How can I replace the word 'and', before the last author with, '&' in both places? The UTM complete template is available [here](https://github.com/utmthesis/utmthesis).

Comment: Since you are using `.bst` files, I have removed the tag `biblatex`: you can't use `biblatex` with `.bst` files.

Comment: Maybe change `FUNCTION {bbl.and} { "and"}` to `FUNCTION {bbl.and} { "\&"}` on line 209?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351557/how-to-customize-a-bibliographic-style#comment863760_351557):

Change the code on line 208 and 209 of `utmthesis-authordate.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and} 
    { "and"}
```

into:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and} 
    { "\&"}
```